# Query: Aggregate en Django para sumar todos los valores

Tags: python, django, sql, sqlite3

Tengo una tabla llamada **Payments**, con dos columnas **Amount** y **Date**

Quiero obtener un diccionario con la suma total de **todos los pagos*** y la suma de **todos los pagos por cada mes**. Debería quedar un diccionaro con la siguiente entrada:

1. Pagos totales
2. Pagos de enero
3. Pagos de febrero
4. Pagos marzo
5. Pagos de abril
6. Pagos de mayo...

Mi **Query** es el siguiente

```
context = {}
total_earnings = orders.Payment.objects.aggregate(earnings = Sum('amount'))
context["total_earnings"] = total_earnings["earnings"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ves de hacer esas consultas para conseguir los **Pagos totales**, considero mas limpio y elegante crear un metodo de clase en el modelo y que lo haga por ti, de la siguiente manera:

```
class Payments(models.Model):
    ...

    @classmethod
    def get_total_earnings(cls):
        return sum([payment.amount for payment in cls.objects.all()])
```

De esta manera puedes conseguir rapidamente y en cualquier momento los **Pagos totales**.

Ahora, para obtener las ganacias totales de cada mes seria de la siguiente manera:

```
earnings = dict()

for i in range(0, 13): 
    payments_months = Payments.objects.filter(date__month = i)
    month_earnings = sum([payment.amount for payment in payments_months])
    earnings[i] = month_earnings
```

Los meses se identifican por numeros, del 1 al 12.

De esta manera tendras las ganacias totales de cada mes, la estructura del diccionario seria algo asi:

```
earnings = {
    '1': 2131241,
    '2': 4234,
    ...
}
```

Identificarias cada mes por su numero. Para añadir los **Pagos totales** al dict:

```
earnings['pagos_totales'] = Payments.get_total_earnings()
```

---

Si tu quieres puedes "personalisar" el diccionario para que se identifiquen las ganacias totales de los meses por "Enero", "Febrero", etc, modificando el for, etc

Por cierto, no se puede obtener los meses asi "January", etc, del campo `DateTimeField`, pues la libreria `datetime` trabaja asi con los meses, que yo sepa, corriganme si estoy mal.

Espero haberte ayudado.